# What's the better way to run function only for once, useEffect or just call the function in Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

We can use `useEffect` to call function for once if we pass empty array as a dependency, but also can **just call functions** without the hook, just call it.

I tried to search what's the better way to call function only for first render, but I could only find posts recommend to use `useEffect` with empty array. But why? Does it more conventional?

What's the better way and why is that?

- Edit)
  I think I made some wrong question. Sorry about it for the first.
  My question is more like this.

We can call function in body so that can be used to every render. I know if we don't suggest second parameter, dependencies, then it will call render on every works. But what's the benefit from using 'useEffect'? We can make a same goal with both - calling in the **useEffect** and **body**.

Comment: If you just call the function, or use `useEffect` without any dependency array, it'll be called every time the component re-renders. `useEffect` combined with an empty array makes it only run once; when the component is rendered and mounted for the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest reading about react's life cycle [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). This is a basic concept and must be mastered.

Calling a function straight in the body can help with debugging (such as using console logs) but is not a good practice and will consume a lot of memory. If this function sets the state, it will create an infinite loop and break your code.

By rule of thumb, never call functions in the body of your component.

Any side effects should either run by user input (pressing a button, typing, etc..) or by useEffect when a state changes.

Take a look at this example:

```
const example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    // Calling a function in the body runs it on every render
    // And is considered a bad practice, as any state change
    // Will cause it to run and consume memory
    myfunction();
     
    const myFunction =() => { console.log('this will run on every render')}

    useEffect(() => {
      //This useEffect acts as componentDidMount
      //It will only run once when the component mounts, since 
      // the dependency array is empty
      console.log('mount');
    }, []);


   useEffect(() => {
      // This will run once on mount and every time
      // count changes. Typical use of useEffect
      // This won't run when text changes.
      console.log('count up', count);
    }, [count]);


   return (
   <>
    <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)} >
     Clicked {counter} times
    </button>
    <input 
       placeholder="Any text here" 
       value ={text} 
       onChange={(e) => {setText(e.target.value)}}
/>
   </>
   )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call functions without the hook, they will be called on every render, this is inefficient and could lead to problems depending on the side effects of your function.

Whereas by wrapping with `useEffect`, the function runs once when the component is first created:

https://jsfiddle.net/dh9b8ox2/1/

In the above fiddle, you'll notice that every time you click the button, the function which is called without the hook gets called, however the fn within the hook only gets called once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest using useEffect if you just want to call the function at once. But however, if you want to use useEffect to call the function only once restrict it by providing empty array or any function or variable into an array that needs to be called only when the value is changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]);
```

// Only re-run the effect if count changes

For the calling function, you need to trigger some event. Which you may not want in your project.
**So, I just want to say. It depends on a scenario where you want to you either of them. Some places you need to use useEffect and some places you just need to use function**